# Is this proof okay?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f:(a, \infty) \to R, \; \; a\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=L, \; L \in R$. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty
> }f(x)=0$

Since $L\in R$

let $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=r$

Case 1 : $r>0$

Now $ \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}x \times \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty \times r = \infty \neq L $

Similarly we can show if $r<0$ $\Rightarrow \displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=-\infty \neq L$

Hence $r=0$ is only possible case

Comment: The format here is Q&A and not discussions. So I changed the title of the question (but perhaps you could find a better title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not OK.  When you say “let $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = r$”, you are assuming this limit exists. I believe you are to prove that fact along with showing the limit is zero.

I also have an issue with doing arithmetic with $\infty$.  We use limits to avoid saying things like “$\infty \times r = \infty$.”

Here is how I would work instead.  If you have established that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} =0$, then write $f(x) = x f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{x}$.  Then use the product rule for limits.  You know $xf(x)\to L$ and $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$, so their product tends to $L \cdot 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a subtle mistake here. How do you know the limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists? So you cannot assume it has the limit $r$. Rather, I would suggest going with $\epsilon$-argument. So find some $M>1$ such that $\dfrac{|L|}{x}<\epsilon$ and $|xf(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $x>M$. Then $|f(x)|\leq\dfrac{1}{x}|xf(x)-L|+\dfrac{|L|}{x}<\dfrac{\epsilon}{M}+\epsilon<2\epsilon$.